# Edge chromium headless mode using java and selenium 3

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge, chromium

I am unable to launch the Edge Chromium in headless mode using the Java and Selenium 3 (3.141.59). I am aware that selenium 3 does not possess much capabilities with current stable version but we don't want to invest in Alpha version of Selenium.
Selenium 4 is not backward compatible, moving to Selenium 4 means making a lot of changes and removing lot of legacy code.
With that said, my question is, is there any solution to handle this problem ?

Comment: _moving to Selenium 4 means making a lot of changes and removing lot of legacy code_ which kind of changes ? could you please elaborate a bit in details.

Comment: Share your code so far for creating your Edge options and any error you get as to why headless isn't working?... I think the option is just 'headless' (no dashes)

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can launch the Edge Chromium browser in headless mode with Selenium 3 but you need to add a reference to the [Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge package](https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools)

I found examples to reference the Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge package in .Net, Python, and JS.

[Use Selenium 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=c-sharp#use-selenium-3)

Unfortunately, I did not get any way to add a reference to the Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge package in JAVA.

So for the JAVA project, you still need to use Selenium 4 Alpha version.